# Immigrant destination by city of entry or city of birth

Tags: data-request, migration

I need a data set that contains variables for immigrant location and city of entry into the US. Alternatively, I could use immigrant location and city of birth outside the US.

The US census contains variables for country of birth, but I need more detailed geographic area. Is there an immigration data set that contains these variables?

Comment: the [american community survey](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/american%20community%20survey%20%28acs%29) has country but not city of birth - but does have `migration puma` if the person moved from one city to another in the past year.  the [survey of income and program participation](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/survey%20of%20income%20and%20program%20participation%20%28sipp%29) 2008 panel topical module #2 has a migration component (questions like `Where the previous home was SAMCTY Where was ...'s previous home?`)